# Is it possible to get a notification after a specific interval time of 5 minutes when the App is closed.? in Ionic and Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is it possible to get a notification after a specific interval time of 5 minutes when the App is closed.?﻿

Comment: It's not obvious what you are asking here.  You want to be notified 5 minutes after the app closes, you want to be notified every 5 minutes even if the app is closed, you want to be notified if the app was closed more than 5 minutes after it was opened?  Please be more specific.

Comment: I want to get the notification when the app is closed. Just as we see in other apps...as we receieve message and something like that.

Comment: I want to be notified every 5 minutes even if the app is closed,

Comment: how would **any** app, not just angular, ever continue to send notifications when the app isn't running?  That doesn't make sense.  You *might* be able to create some sort of app that is a background service on your target device type that can send notifications, but that wouldn't be an angular or ionic app...

Comment: Just compare my question with "Whatsapp".....If this app is closed...then R u getting the notification that "XYZ" person sent you the message.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use $interval for this purpose.
Refer this link for more details
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/timeout-interval.html

Comment: just because they use the word "interval" doesn't automatically mean that `$interval` is a solution. I's not clear what the OP really wants to do, but most anything that involves the app being closed would not allow `$interval` to be used.

Comment: I just wanted to demonstrate the issue that I am facing is: Suppose I have closed the app and after a specific amount of time I want to display some  notification (Any Simple XYZ notification) then what will be the solutions for it.

Comment: use local notification plugin